# Mathematica doesn't give an answer to what wolframalpha answers

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to calculate

> Sum[(1/n)^(n), {n, 1, Infinity}]

But mathematica outputs the input directly. What is the problem?
when I put the same expression into wolframalpha, it gives me the answer but not mathematica.

Comment: Use `NSum` in Mathematica to get a numerical approximation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mathematica `Sum` just returns input means MMA doesn't  find an analytical answer

The sum seems to be convergent

```
SumConvergence[(1/n)^(n), n]
(* True *)
```

Numerically result

```
NSum[(1/n)^(n), {n, 1, Infinity}]
(*1.29129*)
```

That's the result from WolframAlpha!